# Reduce Logical Expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have one week trying to solve this problem to no avail: $\lnot (p \lor q) \land r \lor \lnot (p \leftarrow \rightarrow (q \lor r))$

Wolfram says the answer is this: $(p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor ( \lnot p \land q) \lor ( \lnot p \land r)$, however I can only get to this:

$(\lnot q \land ((\lnot p \land r) \land (p \land \lnot r))) \lor ((q \lor r) \land \lnot p)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First, here's a [Basic MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting those formulas. Second, by 'solve' you mean putting it in disjunctive normal form?  Third, can you show us how you got to where you did? Fourth, I can already see an issue with parentheses: you really should add some parentheses to avoid any ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that $a \land  b \lor c \leftrightarrow (a \land  b) \lor c$, then the DNF of your expression can be found this way.

$(\lnot (p \lor q) \land r) \lor \lnot (p \leftrightarrow (q \lor r) )$

$(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (p \oplus (q \lor r) )$

$(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (p \land \lnot (q \lor r) ) \lor (\lnot p \land  (q \lor r) )$

$(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r) \lor (p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \land  q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$

And since $a \lor (a \land b) \leftrightarrow a$:

$(p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r) \lor (\lnot p \land  q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$